# How do you programmatically run Static Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, envdte, static-code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm working on a solution to localize legacy applications. I've written a Visual studio add-in using EnvDte that automates the process of setting the "Localizable" flag for every form in the solution to true, which is a critical step for extracting resources on form designers. I am now trying to deal with any text that is set programmatically, text that trigger the [Globalization (CA13##)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/globalization-warnings) warnings.

```
designer.Visible = true;
var host = (IDesignerHost)designer.Object;
var provider = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(host.RootComponent);
var typeDescriptor = provider.GetExtendedTypeDescriptor(host.RootComponent);
if (typeDescriptor == null)
    continue;

var propCollection = typeDescriptor.GetProperties();
var propDesc = propCollection["Localizable"];
if (propDesc != null && host.RootComponent != null &&
    (bool?)propDesc.GetValue(host.RootComponent) != true)
{
    try
    {
        propDesc.SetValue(host.RootComponent, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log the error
    }

    // save changes
}
```

I've been able to run it manually from the menu using: *Analyze -> Run Code Analysis -> On Solution* to get a list of issues, but I would like to automate this step with another add-in that runs and extracts the results.

Are there any resources that point to accessing the build warnings or the results of the code analysis?

Are there any solutions that already do this using EnvDte or Roslyn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to glean enough information to put together the add-in. Put simply, you use `_dte.ExecuteCommand()`

1. Initialize the command:

   ```
   // nothing to see here...
   _package = package ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));

   var commandService = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
   if (commandService == null)
       return;
   _dte = (DTE2)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
   var menuCommandId = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
   var menuItem = new MenuCommand(MenuItemCallback, menuCommandId);
   commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);

   _events = _dte.Events.BuildEvents;
   // since static code analysis is a sort of build you need to hook into OnBuildDone
   _events.OnBuildDone += OnBuildDone;
   ```
2. Trigger the analysis

   ```
   private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       _dte.ExecuteCommand("Build.RunCodeAnalysisonSolution");
   }
   ```
3. Extract errors in the OnBuildDone event

   ```
   private void OnBuildDone(vsBuildScope scope, vsBuildAction action)
   {
       Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() =>
       {
           _dte.ExecuteCommand("View.ErrorList", " ");
           var errors = _dte.ToolWindows.ErrorList.ErrorItems;
           for (int i = 1; i <= errors.Count; i++)
           {
               ErrorItem error = errors.Item(i);
               var code = error.Collection.Item(1);
               var item = new
               {
                   error.Column,
                   error.Description,
                   error.ErrorLevel,
                   error.FileName,
                   error.Line,
                   error.Project
               };
               error.Navigate(); // you can navigate to the error if you wanted to.
           }
       });
   }
   ```